# How to store the document's style file in a subdirectory?

Tags: packages, document-classes, folders

I have a journal specific document style as two files `svglov3.clo` and `svjour3.cls`.
I don't want to install them, so I keep them in the article's current directory.
But I like to keep only the files that I can edit in the current directory.
So I would prefer to put them in a sub-directory `./SVJour3` and use

```
\documentclass{SVJour3/svjour3}
```

This would actually work, but `svjour3.cls` has this command `\input{svglov3.clo}`.
So I can put `svjour3.cls` in a separate dir, but I have to keep `svglov3.clo` in current dir.
Is there a workaround for this? Some variable that I can set in a Makefile?

Comment: Have you considered installing the `sv*.*` files in a directory that's searched automatically by your TeX distribution? That way, you wouldn't have to concern yourself with the precise locations of the files in question. Which TeX distribution do you use, incidentally?

Comment: I have TEXLive, the issue is that I don't want to be looking for these specific style files when
I change the computer. They belong exactly with this single document.

Comment: You can set the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to be `.:./SVJour3/:`

Comment: `\documentclass{SVJour3/svjour3}`  is always an error even though sometimes latex does not catch it. The argument to documentclass and usepackage are _names_ not file paths. If the class has a `\ProvidesClass` line then you get an error warning you that the name is wrong, even though the file may load an otherwise appear to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to be

```
.:./SVJour3/:
```

In this way the directory `SVJour3` is searched after the current directory and before `texmf`.

Answer (score 4):

create in the documents directory a new one called `texmf`. And then put the class file into `texmf/tex/latex/`. Before you run your document define

```
export TEXMFHOME=texmf
```

assuming that you are already in the documents directory. Then TeX searches for the files recursively in the texmf directory. Another possibility is to save the class file into the default users local one which is `~/texmf`. Then you do not need the export command.